# QMainWindow:showMaximized only works the first time it is called

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a function `button_max_slot` that use `showMaximized` to maximize the window, and another function `button_restore_slot` to restore the window's size and place. the first time I call the `button_max_slot` it works great, then I use `button_restore_function` to restore window's size and place. But the second time I call the `button_max_slot` to maximize the window, it didn't work. I call `self.isMaximized()` and it returns true, but actually the window doesn't maximized.What should I do to fix this problem?Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    last_geometry = None
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(960, 540)

        self.ButtonMax = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.ButtonMax.setObjectName("ButtonMax")
        self.ButtonMax.setText("Max")
        self.ButtonMax.move(100, 100)

        self.ButtonRestore = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.ButtonRestore.setText("Restore")
        self.ButtonRestore.setObjectName("ButtonRestore")
        self.ButtonRestore.move(300, 100)
        self.ButtonRestore.setEnabled(False)

        self.ButtonMax.clicked.connect(self.button_max_slot)
        self.ButtonRestore.clicked.connect(self.button_restore_slot)

    def button_max_slot(self):
        self.last_geometry = self.geometry()
        self.showMaximized()
        self.ButtonRestore.setEnabled(True)
        self.ButtonMax.setEnabled(False)

    def button_restore_slot(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.last_geometry)
        self.ButtonRestore.setEnabled(False)
        self.ButtonMax.setEnabled(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myshow = MyWindow()
    myshow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Why don't you just use `self.showNormal()`?

Comment: What platform are you testing on? I find it surprising that `setGeometry` works on a maximised window. On my Linux system (with Openbox WM), maximised windows cannot be manually resized. And indeed, when I try the example code, the resize button does nothing (which is normal, and expected). The behaviour of your WM seems broken/illogical. Also, saving the geometry before maximisation is (or should be) redundant.

Comment: I am testing on windows 11. @ekhumoro . And I found that `setGeometry` and `resize` both works on a maximized window on my computer.  I get it , next time I will use `showNormal()` instead of saving the geometry and  then use `setGeometry` to restore the window geometry, thank you.

Comment: I have updated my questions, @eyllanesc

Comment: `self.showNormal()` works, thank you. But I still want to know why this method doesn't work. I called the `self.isMaximized()` function and it returned true even though the window is not maximized.  @musicamante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Use `showNormal()` instead of `setGeometry()` to restore the window state.

### Explanation

While not intuitive, it's still possible to set a geometry of a window even if its state *should **not*** allow it, and that's because setting the state of a window is *not* the same as setting its geometry.

Simply put, setting the window state tells the underlying platform/window manager to "choose" the geometry of the window based on the specified state, while setting the geometry asks the system to explicitly set the position and size of the window. Whether the system allows it, is another story.

An important thing to consider is that a QWidget (even a top level one, including a QDialog or a QMainWindow) is *not* the actual window shown on the screen. What you see is the [QWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html) (an abstract representation of the system's window for that widget), which is what actually *contains* the QWidget (or any of its inherited classes). Setting the state acts on the QWindow, while setting the geometry normally acts on the contained widget, excluding the possible window frame.

For instance, I'm able to reproduce your issue on my Linux system, but [ekhumoro cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804416/qmainwinodwshowmaximized-only-works-the-first-time-it-is-called?noredirect=1#comment123406287_69804416), even though we both are using Linux (we're both using *similar* window managers, but they're still different: he's on OpenBox, I'm on FluxBox). Furthermore, I get inconsistent behavior after pressing the "Max" button, even if using the system features.

The fact that [you got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804416/qmainwinodwshowmaximized-only-works-the-first-time-it-is-called?noredirect=1#comment123414785_69804416) a maximized window state even if it doesn't *look* like it is, is exactly related to that: the *state* is maximized, the geometry isn't (because you changed it).

Consider it the other way around: you can manually resize a window in order to *precisely* occupy the whole available screen size, but that doesn't make it *maximized*: you can still probably see the "maximize" button in it's title bar (not the "normalize" one), and maybe even the window borders that are normally hidden when the window is *actually* maximized.

Note that the inconsistent behavior shown on different OS or window managers relies on two sides: the OS/wm implementation and Qt attempts to use a "standardized" behavior across all systems.

The solution is simple: just restore the state using `showNormal()` instead of `setGeometry()`.

It usually works on all systems, with the exception of some very specific window managers on linux (and maybe some "non standard" behavior in recent Windows/MacOS versions), but it's the *accepted* approach.

For those cases, you might consider storing and *restoring* the geometry by overriding the top level window's [`changeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent), checking if the `event.type()` is a `WindowStateChange` and eventually decide the behavior based on the current [`windowState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#windowState) and the [`oldState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindowstatechangeevent.html#oldState) of that event.
Remember that window states are *flags*, so they can be an `OR` combination of [`Qt.WindowState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowState-enum) enums.

Comment: I did notice that after I used `setGeometry` to restore the window state, it was the "normalize" button instead of the "maximize" button in it's titlebar. And now I understand the reason, thank you very much!

Comment: @Trayvon001 you're very welcome. Just a small, unrelated, but still important suggestion: common convention suggests to use capitalized names only for classes and constants (at least on Python): for instance, your code should use `buttonMax` and `buttonRestore`. While that might seem a minor issue, it's actually *really* important for code readability (and, thus, easier code navigation and debugging). You can read more on the topic on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (aka, PEP-8).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read the official style guide and change my code style

Comment: @musicamante Setting the window state isn't completely separate from setting the geometry. The WM must save the geometry internally before maximisation so that it can restore it upon normalisation. (NB: on my system, programmatically setting the geometry does not override the restored geometry). It is clearly a bug to allow setting the geometry during maximisation. This is confirmed by the fact that the window state isn't reset and the title-bar buttons aren't updated. That is broken behaviour, not merely inconsistent.